# Vertex AI forecasting AutoML datatype mismatch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I could train the vertex AI AutoML forecating model but when I do batch prediction I get following error

> Batch prediction job batch_prediction encountered the following
> errors:
>
> ```
> Column "sales" expects type: NUMBER, the actual type is: STRING.
> ```

Below is a sample of test set I am passing for batch prediction in big query.

According to the documentation for batch prediction we have to send some training/historical data and forecasting dates. I did just that.

[image]

Comment: Google recommend you to use the same input format for trainning and prediction. Seams you have trained your model using a input format here the column sales were a numeric type, and now in the prediction, as all fields are `null` the automatic schema recognition (used when you imported the data) has set it as a string type. Delete this table and import the data again defining the schema manually, and set sales as a numeric field.

Comment: No @ewertonvsilva, for btach prediction we have to provide historical and future dates both in one dataset. so some sales values will be numeric and some will be empty string.
I am referring to this documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/batch-predictions?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=unpaidsoc&utm_campaign=CDR_pri_aiml_5-qjrpjde5s_AISimplified_072221&utm_content=description#tabular

Comment: @ewertonvsilva, I have just updated the photo of data, you can see how my btach prediction data looks like. Any help if highly appreciated.

Comment: Could please check the schema of the table input table ? check the data type of the sales column after create the table in BQ. Add a print of it if possible.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried to create data set in VertexAI directly from Google Cloud Storage. The model trained as usual but now the evaluated set (from model) had sales column as string. So may be because the dataset was imported GCS the dataype picked was String and sales in batch_prediction will always be string. So this time batch_prediction actually worked because schema in training and testing were consistent.

Comment: Good to hear. I will post a final answer about it, please consider accepting/upvoting in order to indicate it solves the problem for helping improving the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google recommend you to use the same input format for ingraining and prediction. Seams you have trained your model using a input format here the column sales were a `numeric` type, and now in the prediction you a using a BigQuery table with the `sales` column as `string`.

Delete this table and import the data again defining the schema **manually**, and set sales as a numeric field, as following:

```
date:DATE,
store_product_id:STRING,
sales:NUMERIC
```